# Queues in Java allows removal of random element. is this bad?

Tags: java, data-structures, queue

`Queue` In Java provides FIFO data structure. Per what I learned, queues have some responsibility to adhere to first-in-first-out behavior. In other terms, you may not remove items from the middle of the queue. However, in Java we can remove random queue elements by using an `iterator`.

Is this a bad design encapsulation-vise? or is the queue data structure supposed to allow this?

```
Queue<String> queue = new LinkedList<String>();
queue.add("e1");
queue.add("e2");
queue.add("e3");
queue.add("e4");

queue.remove("e3");
```

Comment: From the documentation: "_Queues typically, but do not necessarily, order elements in a FIFO (first-in-first-out) manner. Among the exceptions are priority queues, which order elements according to a supplied comparator, or the elements' natural ordering, and LIFO queues (or stacks) which order the elements LIFO (last-in-first-out)...._" More reading [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html)

Comment: I thought that was rather to highlight behavior of priority queues and such implementations.

Comment: Comes from `Queue extends Collection`. It is either that or `UnsupportedOperationException` and I hate both equally. It was a big surprise when moved from the strict `LSP` of `C++` to `Java`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Queue` obviously inherits some of this added functionality by being part of the `Collection` hierarchy. From a polymorphic standpoint, it is beneficial to have `Queue` act like any other `Collection` as it increases the portability of the data structure.

From a design perspective, I wouldn't say it's bad necessarily. Imagine a queue/line at a grocery store. There are situations where a customer might need to be removed from the middle of the line. This particular implementation of a queue supports that, which can be useful.

While you could argue that the additional methods could let you shoot yourself in the foot, you could easily create an implementation of `Queue` that doesn't allow things like `remove(Object)` or `iterator.remove()` if you wanted a strict `Queue`.

Answer (score 3):

> Per what I learned, queues have some responsibility to adhere to first-in-first-out behaviour.

You have probably been reading a text book or some lecture notes or something that describe how an idealised FIFO queue works.  But what you have failed to realise is that not all queues are FIFO.  Not in the real world, and not in computer systems.  (For instance, if (hypothetically) the President Obama went to a busy MacDonalds restaurant, you would find that he was immediately moved to the front of the queue.  That's a queue behaving in a non-FIFO fashion.)

Anyway, the Java `Queue` is an interface for any kind of queue, not just FIFO queues.  It also supports priority queues, and any other queuing semantics you could dream up ... if you care to provide your own implementation class.

The other point is that the `remove(E)` operation is not providing the "next customer please" operation.  It is the equivalent of a customer deciding that they really would prefer a pizza ... and walking out of the door.  An idealized queue doesn't support this, but usable library classes do ... because applications need to be able to do this kind of thing.

The bottom line is that Java `Collection` class hierarchy (including clue `Queue`) is designed to be useful and easy to use, rather than to rigidly fit someone's abstract model of data structures.

---

> But then Queue may allow a sneakIn method, that lets you sneak in to the middle of a queue - where is that method?

Well, since most real applications don't need it, it isn't there.  (If that was a common use-case, such a method would be provided, in specific queue implementation classes even if not in the `Queue` interface.)

Once again, Java classes and interfaces are specified for their utility and usability in real programs, not (in this case) so they can model POTUS in a burger joint.

> Probably I am brain washed by text book definitions and C/C++ labs that I did at school.

An alternative explanation is that you mistook the true purpose of the definitions, etcetera.

Comment: Yes, I had thought of similar examples. But then `Queue` may allow a `sneakIn` method, that lets you sneak in to the middle of a queue - where is that method? Probably I am brain washed by text book definitions and C/C++ labs that I did at school.

Answer (score 1):

Java Queue is not necessarily FIFO. Queue API says

`Queues typically, but do not necessarily, order elements in a FIFO (first-in-first-out) manner`.

It depends on implementation, for instance PriorityQueue is not FIFO but LinkedList that you used is FIFO.

Queue.remove() API does not say it removes a random element, it says

```
Retrieves and removes the head of this queue.
```

In your example it had to be

```
queue.remove();
```

and it would remove `e1`

Comment: Yes, but overloaded `remove` lets you remove item from middle of the queue, which is against the principle of least astonishment for me.

Comment: Well, but this would be breaking Queue.remove contract, it says "removes the head of the queue"